# "ResourceContainerAccessDenied" returned as value of CloudTask.ExecutionInformation.FailureInformation.Code but not in TaskFailureInformationCodes

Tags: azure-batch

I have a .net core 3.0 application using the Microsoft.Azure.Batch 12.0.0 C# nuget package.

I create a job containing one task with a resource file like this (pseudo codeish):

```
var source = ResourceFile.FromStorageContainerUrl(settings.Input.Container.GetAccessUrl());
var cloudTask = new CloudTask(_taskId, commandline)
{
    ...
    ResourceFiles = new[] { source, },
    ...
 }
 await _batchClient.JobOperations.AddTaskAsync("jobid", cloudTask, 
 cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

when i now request the status of the task

```
 var cloudJob = await _batchClient.JobOperations.GetJobAsync("jobId", cancellationToken: 
 cancellationToken);
 var cloudTask = cloudJob.ListTasks().SingleOrDefault();
 var code = cloudTask.ExecutionInformation.FailureInformation,Code
```

code can be of value "ResourceContainerAccessDenied" if indeed we do not have access to the ResourceCondainer - "ResourceContainerAccessDenied" is *not* 
a member of [Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Common.TaskFailureInformationCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.common.taskfailureinformationcodes?view=azure-dotnet) and not documented anywhere as far as i can see.

Is this a bug in the Azure Batch C# SDK? Am i overlooking something? Where can i get a list of all possible code values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that this error code is not included in the C# SDK is indeed a bug.
I will be fixing this bug as part of an upcoming SDK release (ETA ~1 week).